# Large set of semen microscope images needed

Tags: statistics, biostatistics, biomedical-engineering

As a course project I have to write an algorithm whose purpose is to analyze a sperm sample (total number, motility etc). In order to do that though, I need to have a sufficient number of images to use during the coding and testing parts.

Do you know if there is any dataset available with semen images? It would also help if the corresponding stats of the images are also given, so that I can use them as a benchmark to see how well my algorithm works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Researchers, male anyway, have tended to collect their own samples.

Comment: Yes, check out the methods for library construction used by one of the authors in this classic paper: http://hogness.stanford.edu/PDFs/62_isolation_and_nucleotide.pdf

Comment: @AMR Yeah, that's a pretty bright idea..  
go ahead and jerk off every single day of the week...

Comment: I wasn't kidding. That is actually what researchers in human sperm do. mdperry gave you a paper where the first author was the source shown in the methods. I have also seen a researcher mention it in a documentary on fertility. And I know of a lecturer who gets one of her male students to provide the lab techs with a fresh sample for her lecture on gametogenesis a few hours before. They set up a microscope with a video camera and project it onto a screen in the lecture hall. It is really quite amazing. This is science and sometimes scientists have to be their own test subjects.

Comment: Also if you want to be taken seriously as a Biologist, you need to learn to use terms such as "Collect a Sample" in place of "jerk off." The Biologists in the room will know what you mean without needing to be indelicate. If you must refer to the method of sample collection, then masturbation is the more appropriate terminology.